# Script help. If div[A] is not empty, fuction[B] operates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please could you help me with writing a script?

If div[id=A]  is not empty, fuction["B"] operates.

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: @Robert haha.. no.  sorry if I was shown too lazy. I am reading w3schools tutorials so I think it could be like.
    <script>
if(['#div_a']) !==''.function.functionB()
</script>

It would definately not work. 

Why I'm looking for the answer is, I know how I can make a formula but I 'm just not really used to making it into a code rule. So, I only need this answer, so I can apply it into another things. 

I am trying to know how to make a trigger and how it should look like

Comment: @JunghoonLee Your question isn't clear. What does 'empty' mean? Is the div empty in the sense that it doesn't contain any child nodes, or that the div doesn't exist at all? It sounds like you need to shore up your understanding of how JavaScript & HTML work together (by which I mean the DOM, or Document Object Model).

Comment: @mattsven I meant Div id="a" doesn't have any child nodes. and thank you so much for letting me know what exactly I need to look more. I will check DOM part at W3schools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="a"><b>not empty div</b></div>
```

JS:

```
if($('#a').html()){
  myFuncB();
}

function myFuncB(){
  alert('my func b!');
}
```

[Check the demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1m6hdqa/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me how to make a trigger for something not already made in code like onblur, or onfocus or onclick. Thank you so much. your script is easy and understandable to my level. Thank you so much. have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

You could try to iterate all the div,check the div's id if it equals to "A",
if does,call the function B.

Here is the code sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            if (divs[i].id == "d1") {
                A();
            }
        }
    }

    function A() {
        alert("A");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer . it helps me to understand how to write following the javascript rule. Yours and manzapanza's asnwer both are really awesomely helping, but I chose easier one that I could use with understanding for my level. hope the day when I can understand your great script, finally comes. Have a nice day.